# Защита и смена контента скачивание js файлов

Tags: javascript, nginx, php7

Не уверен в правильности меток, но не знаю как сделать.

Есть файл js на сервере, веб сервер nginx.

Есть ссылка для скачивания https://domain.com/handler.js
Хочу установить проверку на рефер и для запрашиваемого домена. Рефер и домен я буду выбирать с базы,так как у нас есть свои клиены.

Использую php nginx.  Как бы мне перехватить запрос на ссылку обработать ее в php логике и отдать нужный контент.

Или натсроить выполнение php скрипта в js файле, как?

Comment: referer и домен можно подделать - вы так не сможете защититься.

Comment: Да, я же указал что и сменна контента.Я не всем одну и ту же логику буду отсылать

Comment: Что такое `сменна контента`? Вы не до конца поняли - referer и домен можно поставить любой при запросе. Это - не защита.

Comment: Изменил заголовок. Да я понимаю что заголовки подделываются, но это лучше чем ничего. К примеру клиент вводит в админке domain.com своего сайта. Он в базе и я проверяю при скачке файла. Да ты можешь подделать заголовок, но ты сначала угадай какой домен надо ввести что бы получить доступ к файлу. Это уже усложняет задачу. Смена контента,к примеру есть одна ссылка на скачивание для каждого клиента, в нем я обрабатываю логику на php. Если не клиент я отдам console.log("Иди лесом") , а если клиент отдам логику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать следующим образом.
В файле конфигурации /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
добавил расширение для **security.limit_extensions = *.js***
в файле
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf

location ~ .(php|***js***)$

В итоге ставлю обработчик на php в файле js и через echo и отдаю нужный контент, можно добавить токен в заголовки для большей надежности.